Cannot connect to Oracle thas uses wallet (certificates) with SQLTools
We have an Oracle database (external supplier) which we want to connect to with certificates. I have in the file tnsnames.ora the next entry:
TESTDB =
  (DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=TESTDB-SERVER)(PORT=2233))
    )
  (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=TESTDB))
  (SECURITY =
     (MY_WALLET_DIRECTORY = D:\testwallet\acc)   
     (SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (TCPS,NTS))
     (SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = FALSE)
  )
)

It works fine with SQL Developer and SQL*Plus,  but I cannot connect with SQLTools.
I tried with the latest version. Is this possible or not supported?
What can I try in SQLTools? Not much possible. SQLTools does see the entries from tnsnames.ora.

You haven't said what the error is, but this is probably off-topic here. You might need to ask the developer of SQLTools, or perhaps more likely the developer of the Oracle driver you are using (this?).

You will probably find that the Oracle connection is with JDBC which builds a dynamic connection string rather than using tnsnames.ora. The Oracle driver you are trying to use may not support encrypted (TCPS) connections.

The error i get is ORA-12154 could not resolve the connect identifier specified.
tnsping  works and i can connect with sqlplus or sql developer using the same tnsnames.ora (TNS_ADMIN pointing to central folder).

You tagged the question with [sqltools] and the other questions with that mostly seem to be about the VSCode extension, from a quick scan. I looked at sqltools.net but it looked a bit random and old. Seems I guessed wrong. You can edit your question to clarify the tool and version you are using. You still might have more luck with the developer, or their forum.

It works here:
Connection Type: Use TNSNAMES.ORA
TNS Admin location: directory path where you UNZIP the wallet
TNS Alias: once admin location is OK, will pop-up list of available ones


I use sqltools from sqltools.net. My question seems to be changed from sqltools to VS Code SQLTools extension. I'm not using an extension so i don't think its exactly the same. I do not have the options you mentioned. I can use TNS and select one from the list or select bypass tnsnames.ora en fill in the host, port and SID (no more options).

What "one of the list" ? One of the tnsnames.ora it founds on your disk or what of the alias it found in it?

i have one tnsnames ora with 20+ entries. When i point to the folder of the tnsnames.ora within sqltools i can select any of the 20+ entries. All the connections of those entries works fine exept those who uses the wallet (entires with the security added) ->
(SECURITY =
(MY_WALLET_DIRECTORY = D:\testwallet\acc)
(SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (TCPS,NTS))
(SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = FALSE)
)

D:\testwallet\acc thus must contain the wallet.* files, the original tnsnames.ora, the keystore.jks... etc. in fact the expanded Wallet zip you downloaded  from your server... is it?

In D:\testwallet\acc i created a new wallet with a self signed certificate in it. Also i added the certificates from the supplier to it. So this folder contains only ewallet.p12, cwallet.sso end the (exported) certificates. Like i said it works fine with SQL Developer so i thought at first that it also would work with othr programs.
I've read about convert the wallet to keystore.jks etc with use of Dbeaver. I will look into that and place all the needed files in the walletfolder. Thank you for your reply.
